# Scrolling Pages like in Jamie Oliver's Recipes app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How to achieve the effect of parallaxing images as seen in Jamie Oliver Recipes app?

[image]

Comment: I think you can try working with images views, layer transforms, a scroll view that spans the whole screen over the image views and scroll view delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be a collectionView and to set the lineSpacing to 0:

```
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let width = collectionView.bounds.width
    let height = collectionView.bounds.height

    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

and stretch the collectionView with auto layout to fit the whole screen.